# Charset of symmetric keys

Tags: key-exchange

I like to know from which charset a symmetric key is generated.

Example: dm-crypt/LUKS

The 128/256 bit (16/32 byte) key comes from /dev/urandom, and would be encoded as base64 string.

So then I have an base64 encoded string (32/64 byte), which come together with an XTS key of same length, what results in an 64 byte string for 128 bit, and 128 byte string for 256 bit keys as masterkey.

But on which charset based this initial 16/32 byte string?

I mean digits are to weak, only lower/uppercase letters too. The complete keyboard chars (ASCII) are used? (possibly weak for 128 bit keys in future) Binary chars or even 1,2+ million possible unicode chars?

I don't know what exactly comes (how many possible chars) from /dev/urandom, and what from these is really used by the encryption scheme (gnupg, dm-crypt/LUKS ...).

Sry for bad english.

I hope anyone can explain the internals.

Comment: /dev/urandom returns binary bytes (think `unsigned chars`)… so the charset range is 0x00-0xFF. Is that what you’re asking?

Answer (score 2):

None. Really: *none*. The key consists of random bits. Modern computers however operate on bytes as smallest entity that can be retrieved from memory. *A CPU doesn't even know what a character set is.*

Character sets are a way of *encoding* a text string to bytes. They consist of a mapping of a character (or other symbols or combining characters) or to one or more bytes. however, not all characters are necessarily printable, and not all bytes or byte combinations may be used to represent characters within a character set. That means that some or many bytes cannot even be represented in a character set.

It is *wrong* to think that every byte in a computer can be mapped to a character. Basically you should only decode those bytes that were generated as an encoded string in the first place.

---

If you need to use the bytes as text then you can indeed encode them using a (binary-to-text) encoding such as base 64.

Now base 64 is text so it in turn needs to use a character encoding whenever it is needed to treat the base 64 as bytes. However, as it  simply uses characters out of the ASCII character set commonly ASCII or the one of the many compatible character sets are used.

Some base 64 encoders will even directly generate bytes that are ASCII encoded. Which is a nuisance if you then want to embed base 64 in an UTF-16 encoded XML format (which is also highly inefficient for base 64, all the more reason *not* to use UTF-16).

Comment: Okay. Now I think I was completely wrong, from my understanding. The main intention was to find out how strong a key is. Maybe I was a bit naive to think, that possibly weak keys are could used in such software. I mean keys who are less secure than the user password itself. Thanks for explaining this.